# How can you sort / order angular material dropdown after localization

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm developing an UI that uses angular i18n for localization. My problem is with drop downs generated from enumerations. I can't figure out how to order them alphabetically depending which language is at hand.

I have tried to use some pipes, but it seems that they are performed before translations are applied. I have also tried to change the order in xlf without any luck.

Is there some way to run localizations directly from component, so I would have localized strings in component where I could order them as I want before sending them to form? Or is there some other way of doing this kind of stuff?

Template:

```
<mat-label i18n="@@dropdown-id">This is test</mat-label>
<mat-select id="dropdown" formControlName="dropdown"required>
<mat-option *ngFor="let enum of enums | enumToArray | slice:1" [value]="enum.key" i18n="@@values-id"> {enum.value, select, apple {Apple} banana {Banana} cucumber {Cucumber}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

messages.fi.xlf (localizations for finnish):

```
<source>
    <x id="ICU" equiv-text="{enum.value, select, apple {...} banana {...} cucumber {...}}"/>
</source>
<target state="final">
    <x id="ICU" equiv-text="{enum.value, select, apple {...} banana {...} cucumber {...}}"/>
</target>
<source>
    {VAR_SELECT, select, apple {Apple} banana {Banana} cucumber {Cucumber} }
</source>
<target state="final">
    {VAR_SELECT, select, apple {Omena} banana {Banaani} cucumber {Kurkku}  }
</target>
```

Any tip for solving this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform i18n trasform from your controller. 
Personally, I've used https://github.com/ngx-translate/core; load the JSON file with the transitions and use ES6's arrays functions (find/foreach).